# Mkl + Eigen vs Mkl Only

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen, intel-mkl

I read some threads, but I still am not sure.

What is the gain of using MKL in Eigen, if you can use MKL only?

I am interested in sparse matrix multiplication, but everything is fine.

Comment: You can use MKL functions with the API of Eigen (with essentially zero overhead). If you prefer MKL's API, there is no gain for you.

Comment: Thanks. That's all, it can be closed (positive feedback)